# module 'site' has no attribute 'getusersitepackages'

Tags: python

My python version is 3.6.4, using the osx system, and ide is pycharm.
The error message is as follows, ask what is the problem, thank you

```
>>>import site
>>>var = site.getusersitepackages()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'site' has no attribute 'getusersitepackages'
```

Comment: Are you using virtualenv by any chance? If yes, you might want to read this. https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/804

Comment: @hikerjobs yes, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
site.USER_SITE()
```

if you get an answer, it might mean that the site package is of an older version since the docs say that site.getusersitepackages() was added only in v3.2
https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-site